# Error calling webservice from Service

Tags: c#, web-services, system.net.webexception

I am referenced a webservice and it works fine on my local machine. But when i promote my code to Test machine, i get below error:

> Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond xx.xx.x.xxx:80

Inner exception displays:

> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) 
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)

Can anyone point me in right direction to check what maybe going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are either using the wrong target address or the web service isn't running. The important message is `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.x.xxx:80`. Can you telnet to that address at port 80, ie can you run `telnet  xx.xx.x.xxx 80` ? If not, there is no-one listening on the server's side

Comment: thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for the pointer. When i Telnet i get nothing (rather get XML wit body as: The request verb is invalid) but how does it work on my local machine but not on Test server.

Comment: looks like we cant ping this IP from this particular server